# np array как добавить в массив?

Tags: python

Есть вот такие массивы

```
n0 = np.array([[2.553, 2.553]])
n1 = np.array([3.553, 4.553])
```

а как их можно объединить что бы получить

```
[[2.553, 2.553], [3.553, 4.553]]
```

Comment: первый ndarray у вас двухмерный. так и было задумано?

Answer (score 0):

```py
n0 = np.array([[2.553, 2.553]])
n1 = np.array([3.553, 4.553])

n = [n0, n1]

print(n)

# [[2.553, 2.553], [3.553, 4.553]]
```

Comment: а если надо будет добавлять в цикле?

Comment: вы сэмулировали вывод. по факту у вас получается не то, что нужно, потому что первый ndarray - двухмерный

Comment: @test так добавьте в цикле, в чем проблема?

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте так:

```
import numpy as np

n0 = np.array([[[2.553, 2.553]]])
n1 = np.array([3.553, 4.553])

# здесь будет ваш цикл, в котором вы добавляете свои списки в кортеж arrays:
arrays = (n0, n1)
# после завершения цикла:

res = np.concatenate(([[x.flatten()] for x in arrays]))
```

`res`, соответственно, будет:

```
[[2.553 2.553]
 [3.553 4.553]]
```